# Why does Chrome resolve websitename.localhost as localhost?

Tags: dns, web-development, google-chrome, localhost, xampp

I've been using .localhost as a TLD for locally hosted sites that I am working on. Usually when I start a new site I create an entry in the apache virutal host configuration file and then add an entry in Windows' `hosts` file to map the address to 127.0.0.1. The address would be something like sitename.localhost

Today I was working on a new site so I added the entry in the virtual hosts file but I forgot to add an entry to the hosts file. To my surprise the site loaded fine in Chrome without mapping the address to 127.0.0.1. However when I tried to load the site in IE and Firefox, it didn't work and my ISP's website showed up instead.

Is there a reason why Chrome does this and other browsers do not? Is this something that is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia entry for .localhost (TLD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost):

> As a top-level domain, the name has traditionally been defined statically in host DNS implementations with address records (A and AAAA) **pointing to the same loopback addresses**.

However, as you have found, it would appear that it's just Chrome and later versions of Opera (possibly the WebKit browsers, so might include Safari also) that appear to do this.

Comment: I was hoping to get an answer that explains why they do this but I guess that is something that only the developers can explain. Thanks!

Comment: "Why" (as I understand it) is explained above and in the linked Wikipedia article. `example.localhost` (TLD) has _traditionally_ pointed to the same loopback address as `localhost` (domain). So that `localhost` (in any form) points to `127.0.0.1`. Chrome (WebKit?) appears to follow this "tradition"; others do not. There is no standard in this respect, so browsers are free to do as they wish.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. That does explain it. It would be cool if other browsers followed that tradition.

Answer (score 7):

From https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

There's [a proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-west-let-localhost-be-localhost-06) to add the **.localhost** domain as a new standard, which will make lives of developers way easier.
It would mean **site.localhost** and everything at ***.localhost** would automatically translate to **127.0.0.1**, without **/etc/hosts** or **dnsmasq** workarounds.

Refer the [RFC here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606).

Comment: That would make much more sense than having each application test for that one special case!